# Kubernetes command logging on Google Cloud Platform for PCI Compliance

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, pci-compliance, pci-dss

Using Kubernetes' `kubectl` I can execute arbitrary commands on any pod such as `kubectl exec pod-id-here -c container-id -- malicious_command --steal=creditcards`

Should that ever happen, I would need to be able to pull up a log saying who executed the command and what command they executed. This includes if they decided to run something else by simply running `/bin/bash` and then stealing data through the tty.

How would I see which authenticated user executed the command as well as the command they executed?

Answer (score 1):

Audit logging is not currently offered, but the Kubernetes community [is working to get it available in the 1.4 release](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/22), which should come around the end of September.

Comment: I saw this in my research but they barely got the initial plan together 9 days ago. I know of several businesses including WePay that would have to be PCI compliant and they are using Kubernetes. Would businesses that require full compliance not be able to use Kubernetes?

Comment: If you ran your application in a container with just the binary (e.g. built from scratch rather than from a fully featured OS like debian or even alpine linux) then the only thing you'd be able to kubectl exec in the container is what was already running. I suppose you could execute it with different commands, but you could also build a binary that takes no flags so that that wasn't possible either. I guess I'm trying to say that audit logging is *one* way to address the compliance requirement, but it likely isn't the only way to do so.